# Conditional Definition with Using in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, initialization, ternary-operator

I want to avoid duplicating code to write to a log file conditionally, as I'm doing below. Is there a better solution in VB.net?

```
If Not System.IO.File.Exists(log_file_address) Then
    Using log_file_stream as New System.IO.StreamWriter(log_file_address)
        log_file_stream.Writeline (current_time_string)
        log_file_stream.Writeline (" ")
        log_file_stream.Writeline (log_message)
        log_file_stream.Close()
    End Using
Else
    Using log_file_stream As IO.StreamWriter = System.IO.File.AppendText(log_file_address)
        log_file_stream.Writeline (current_time_string)
        log_file_stream.Writeline (" ")
        log_file_stream.Writeline (log_message)
        log_file_stream.Close()
    End Using
End If
```

Perhaps something like:

```
Using log_file_stream as If(System.IO.File.Exists(log_file_address), _
                            System.IO.File.AppendText(log_file_address), _
                            New System.IO.StreamWriter(log_file_address))
    log_file_stream.Writeline (current_time_string)
    log_file_stream.Writeline (" ")
    log_file_stream.Writeline (log_message)
    log_file_stream.Close()
End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx) for the constructor of the `StreamWriter` with parameters takes a file path string and Boolean switch to indicate if it should over append or not. Noted that if file does not exist, this parameter has no effect, and the constructor creates a new file.

So a change to and let the constructor take care of the check to see if file exists.

```
Using log_file_stream as New System.IO.StreamWriter(log_file_address, True)
    'Write to log file...
End Using
```

Comment: just replace the `True` with `System.IO.File.Exists(log_file_address)`

Comment: Thanks, very clean and good insight into where to look for these sorts of issues.